# How to fix intellij keymap to old keymap after 2019 update Mac OS?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keymapping

So I've recently installed Intellij and it seems the Mac OS keymap I used to use no longer exists.

It used to be CMD + N for search classes and CMD + SHIFT + N for files, now it's changed to CMD + O for classes and CMD + SHIFT + O for files.  Also it used to be CMD + F4 to close tab, now it's CMD + W.

Is there any way to fix this so I can use the same keymapping it used to be?

These are the only options I have, and none of them give the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [changed](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/?_ga=2.6214771.1912417947.1565581646-1531330835.1556592966#v2019-2-editor) the default keymap for macOS from `Mac OS X` to `macOS 10.5+`. In case you want to revert classic shortcuts back, choose "Intellij Idea Classic" keymap: 
[image: Intellij Idea Classic keymap]